# return value from firebase functions and store it to a variable in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-cloud-functions, recaptcha

I have created a function to verify recaptcha using firebase functions, I don't know how do I respond so that I would save the response as (e.g. isabot = false) or something in my html code, so to let the user click on submit or not let the user to click on submit.

Comment: Does [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/guard-your-web-content-from-abuse-with.html) article answer your question? I think that the example here does something similar

Comment: No, It redirects me to somewhere and shows me the response, but I want to use the response of recaptcha to let the user click submit or not let the user click submit.

Comment: Can you please share your code? we can't help you to achieve the desired behavior without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)